# parsing text file for a line, in python

Tags: python, file, parsing, text

system generates a text file. it contains more than 100 lines. i like to get a line in the file.

```
some text **
Actions Pending are: Action-1, Action-2,....Action-3 (this is another new line)
some text**
```

need to get the Actions in pending to array.

i used

```
for index in text:
    rc.logMessage(str(index))
```

it is printing each character at a time not the line.

help me how can i parse this file to get actions into an array.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Something like:

```
d = """some text **
Actions Pending are: Action-1, Action-2, Action-3
some text**
"""
res = []
for line in re.findall('Actions Pending are: (.+)', d):
    res.extend([action.strip() for action in line.split(',')])
['Action-1', 'Action-2', 'Action-3']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this:

```
pendingActions = []
textToSearch = 'Actions Pending are:'
for line in open(filename, 'r'):
    line = line.strip()
    if line and line.startswith(textToSearch):
        pendingActions.extend([x.strip() for x in line[len(textToSearch):].split(',') if x.strip()])
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to iterate over the *file*, not a string read from the file.

```
with open(filename) as text:
    for line in text:
         rc.logMessage(some_function_of_the_line(line))
```

Iterating over the file gives you lines; iterating over a string gives you characters / bytes.

Answer (score 2):

You want `str.splitlines()` http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines

```
for index in text:
    rc.logMessage(str(index))
```

becomes:

```
for index in text.splitlines():
    rc.logMessage(str(index))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
with file("your_file") as logfile:
   result = [line for line in logfile if line.startswith("Actions pending")]
```

This way in result you will have all the actions lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
    search_string = 'Actions Pending are: '
    for line in open('yourfile.txt', 'r').readlines():
      if line.startswith(search_string):
        actions = line[len(search_string):].split(',')
        break
    print actions
```

Artsiom was faster: [parsing text file for a line, in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940500/parsing-text-file-for-a-line-in-python/6940611#6940611), maybe my version is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner (for fun):

```
s = """some text **
Actions Pending are: Action-1, Action-2, Action-3
Actions Pending are: Action-4, Action-5, Action-6
some text**"""

[a for ln in s.splitlines() if ln.startswith("Actions Pending") for a in ln[len("Actions Pending are: "):].split(', ')]
------
['Action-1', 'Action-2', 'Action-3', 'Action-4', 'Action-5', 'Action-6']
```

To use a file instead of a string, replace s.splitlines() with f.readlines(). Note, I wouldn't use this code in practice; It is just for fun.